# React.js: Passing props to MobX Store

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm trying to pass the props object from App.js into a MobX store, like so:

```
//ui_store.js
import {message_construction_logic, App} from "../App";

export class UiStore {
    starting_array = [<ChoosePostType ui_store={ui_store} go_to_anchor_link={this.props.go_to_anchor_link} />];
...
```

In App.js I have setup the function to be passed as a prop as follows:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.go_to_anchor_link = this.go_to_anchor_link.bind(this)
    };

    // METHODS ===========================================


    go_to_anchor_link = (anchor_id) => {

        const scroll_target = document.getElementById(anchor_id);
        console.log('anchor_id', anchor_id); // returns "question_leads", which is correct

        if (scroll_target) {
            console.log('scroll_target', scroll_target);
            smoothScroll(scroll_target);
        }
    };
...
```

The child component attempting to receive the props is throwing an undefined error. Am I not exporting the props correctly?

Comment: Why store [`React elements`](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwYQFg9hDOCmAKMAuAVAngB1gAgK4EsB9aJCAJ1gF4BvA40igX2wHMJDTCBDAOwGNIZQgBt8PANY0kYfNAB0GMhAzy2HdrwHkRY8cwD0APiA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=) in a MobX store? Why not store the data there, and derive the React elements from that data in your components' render method?

Comment: The pattern I plan to use is to have each step in a sequence push the next component in line, into an array that App.js renders (think of a "Next Step" button as the trigger). How would the pattern you have in mind implement that?

Comment: You could e.g. have a variable `currentStep` which contains a number representing the current step in the sequence, and then just have `if (uiStore.currentStep === 0) { return <ChoosePostType ui_store={ui_store} go_to_anchor_link={this.props.go_to_anchor_link} />; }` etc. in your React component.

Comment: Yes I thought about using a number count to progressively switch on new steps. I feel the array is easier to reason about and manipulate as desired. For example if someone chooses  a different option in the very first step then I could just clear the same array, instead of switching off a bunch of state variables for the last track. Step one has 5 paths so I thought that would create a lot of unnecessary code compared to an array push pattern. Just my thoughts and I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm not saying it's wrong, but it's very unorthodox and not a common practice. It's very error prone to store React elements in state instead of deriving the elements from state/props in the render method.

Comment: Ok, I see. I think I'll rebuild this using state as a selector instead of a JSX store. Thank you for the higher level guidance